# while copying file from blobstorage and writing in to Azure File Share using create file in Azure logic APP creates blank files with NULL contents

Tags: logic, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, storage-file-share

I am getting blank files (files with null  values) with size of 3MB.while creating it through Logic APP after copying from blob and create file using create file trigger using File Share connector. the file shows size after creating in fileshare location but while opens nothing is there and all contents are empty. How to overcome this issue. any alternatives.

Comment: Null and 3 mb? arent they contradicting? can you provide more information on what you are receiving?

Comment: The Document is created as blank with no values (its an excel document , so there is no records are visible) but the when i check the size of the document it shows as 2M/3MB.